# Cache remains stale for custom blocks after editing

Tags: 8, caching

My Drupal 8 website consists of multiple custom blocks created from the drupal backend user interface.

As I went from dev to production settings and activating `Internal Dynamic Page Cache` (set to 1 minute), the custom block content doesn't change on the actual site after editing (for both anonymous and authenticated users). If I go back to editing mode, the changes are persisted as expected.

The changes are visible when I clear the caches (i.e. drush cache-rebuild). I don't have any issues with my own blocks that implements the Block plugin and has a max-age set. Nodes works works as expected too.

What could be wrong?

Comment: When you configure you block, [is it set to forever?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gjmJK.jpg)?

Comment: @NoSssweat where can I find this option?

Answer (score 0):

hope this works ...

```
<?php
abstract class BlockBase extends PluginBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
  /**
   * Returns generic default configuration for block plugins.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An associative array with the default configuration.
   */
  protected function baseConfigurationDefaults() {
    return array(
      'label' => '',
      'module' => $this->pluginDefinition['module'],
      'label_display' => BlockInterface::BLOCK_LABEL_VISIBLE,
      'cache' => array(
        'max_age' => 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

refer to this link [block cache api is removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2222293)

The following block cache constants have been replaced with the combination of the cache.max_age and ::getCacheContexts() return values (or bubbled cache contexts) on blocks:

```
DRUPAL_NO_CACHE (equivalent: cache.max_age = 0)
DRUPAL_CACHE_CUSTOM (equivalent: cache.max_age = 0 + Cache::keyFromQuery())
DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE (equivalent: cache.max_age >0 + user.roles)
DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER (equivalent: cache.max_age >0 + user)
DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE (equivalent: cache.max_age >0 + url)
DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL (equivalent: cache.max_age >0, no cache contexts)
```